# i am getting error while requesting api in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

below is my code where i am using XMLHttpRequest but it is showing below error, can anyone help me out with the issue.

> error 1 : open.html:24 OPTIONS
>   https://proxy.api.deepaffects.com/text/generic/api/latest/sync/text_recognise_emotion?apikey=xAur1Q9uSgipes2jnCBSTzPj8mJn4LP9
>   404 (Not Found) (anonymous) @ open.html:24 error 2 : Failed to load
>   https://proxy.api.deepaffects.com/text/generic/api/latest/sync/text_recognise_emotion?apikey=xAur1Q9uSgipes2jnCBSTzPj8mJn4LP9:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute. open.html:15

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "content": "it is not good"
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://proxy.api.deepaffects.com/text/generic/api/latest/sync/text_recognise_emotion?apikey=xAur1Q9uSgipes2jnCBSTzPj8mJn4LP9");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: You want to do that with `PHP` or such. In the `back-end`.

Comment: No, i want to use it in my zendesk app

Comment: It does — not — work. Due to `Same-Origin-Policy` in the browser.

Comment: may i know the solution for that

Comment: You want to do use `cURL` with `PHP` or such. As said.

Comment: i have done this in java, it worked successfully, i am not handy with XMLHttpRequest so help me out.

Comment: You want to do use cURL with PHP or such. As said. – AjAX.

Comment: It does — not — work with `XHR`. You MUST use a language on the server. Like `Java` or `PHP`. %)P

Comment: No. i do not want to use cURL and Php

Comment: Then ask the `API` if they add your `domain` to `CORS`!

Comment: i want to do it  in javascript  only

Comment: I really want to help you. But you do — not — believe in `Error 2`. That is suffering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803394/cors-credentials-mode-is-include

Comment: Hey AjAX, can you tell me that whether this problem can be solved or no, is there any other solution for it, i can't use Server side script in my problem so i have only javascript to write

Comment: If you cannot use `server-side` it does — not — work. Unfortunately. %)P

Comment: i have to use it on Zendesk server. it is a functionality i want ti implement on Zendesk application.