# React fetch, “credentials: include”, breaks my entire request and I get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, api, rest

### Summary:

I'm doing a fetch request in React to my Node.js server.

Whenever I do NOT include `credentials: "include"` and in my fetch request, the request is successfully made to the server and returned to the client.

**However**, when I do include `credentials: "include"`, like the below:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/',
    {   method: "GET", 
       'credentials': 'include',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:3000/',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })

}) ....
```

I get this preflight error:

**`login:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`**

### Context:

---

**Why do I need to include either of those?**

1. I think it's obvious why I need to include the "headers", I'm using cors and if I don't include `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:3000/'` then the server will not accept the request.
2. Why do I need to include the "credentials" if it works without it? Because if I do not include "credentials" while the fetch request executes correctly, the session cookie will not be sent to the server from my client UNLESS I include `credentials: "include"`. If I delete all the headers and include `mode: 'no-cors'`, then the fetch request executes and the session cookie is sent to the server, but obviously I get an opaque response, and I need to be using cors anyways.

### Attempts:

---

There are a lot of stack overflow questions **SIMILAR** to this, but not exact, thus their solutions don't work.

Here are some things I have tried that didn't work:

1. This is already on my server, but someone suggested trying it on the client side so I did: `'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS',`
2. `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',`
3. `'withCredentials': 'true',`
4. `Origin: 'http://localhost:3000/auth',`
5. `crossorigin: true,`
6. And yes, I've already set up a proxy (which helped solve a prior issue) as such: `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"`
7. I've tried many more other solutions to no avail, I'm certain I've read, if not all, the vast majority of all questions relating to do with this issue and the corresponding answers.
   My server is setup correctly, which is why I didn't include any code from it.

In an ideal world I wouldn't need to use `credentials: "include"` for the session cookie to be sent back to my server, but that is the cause of another solution I had to implement.

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

### TLDR:

---

My preflight request does pass whenever I do NOT include `credentials: "include"`, but the session cookie is not passed.

The session cookie is passed when I do include `credentials: "include"` and `mode: 'no-cors'`, however, I receive an opaque response and I need to use cors.

Finally, when I combine the two (cors and credentials), I my preflight request fails with the below error:

`login:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Comment: Did you inspect the HTTP request sent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this most likely comes from your server.
Do you have cors npm package installed in the backend ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

You will need ton configure it aswell.

Most likely in your index.js file.

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin : http://localhost:3000 (Whatever your frontend url is) 
  credentials: true, // <= Accept credentials (cookies) sent by the client
})

app.use("/api/whatever/the/endpoint", yourRouter);
```

This has to be set before any route.
Origin can be an array of whitelisted (allowed) domains to communicate with your backend api.

Comment: I did have cors installed and setup on the backend, but not like how you did it. I used a variety of techniques found on StackOverflow, but yours is the only one that worked. Thank you!

Comment: Using credentials: true in my nodejs and credentials: 'include' in my frontend worked.

Answer (score 6):

The correct explanation here is that the server was sending back the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response (as described in the error message).

Without credentials this is acceptable. However, to quote the [Mozilla CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards),

> When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, instead of specifying the "*" wildcard.

Furthermore, if you were already using the [npm cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options) to handle setting the response headers, note that

> The default configuration is the equivalent of:

```js
{
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
```

So you have to explicitly configure it. This is why [@yeeeehaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351799/react-fetch-credentials-include-breaks-my-entire-request-and-i-get-an-error#answer-63385410) worked - they suggested explicitly setting the `origin` option which translates into setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` behind the scenes.

Note that as an alternative solution, instead of explicitly setting `origin` (i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) you can [reflect the request's origin back](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options) as its value. The `cors` middleware conveniently provides for this through its configuration.

> Boolean - set origin to true to reflect the request origin, as defined by req.header('Origin'), or set it to false to disable CORS.

```js
origin: true
```

On Stack Overflow this has also been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i?rq=1), and on the reverse proxy level [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400059/nginx-using-cors-with-credentials) (for NGINX). Maybe the most similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803394/cors-credentials-mode-is-include?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accept requests from multiple different domains you could do something like this also:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

As documented here: https://www.zigpoll.com/blog/cors-with-express-and-fetch