# Nginx using CORS with credentials

Tags: nginx, cors, credentials

I'm working on building a web application that communicates with a Laravell API through an Nginx server. I tried following the directions on the Nginx website for [wide open cors](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html), but it doesn't like the wild card response when sending credentials.

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.****.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

The API server requires a Bearer access token to authenticate, and each endpoint is at its own path on the server. What is the correct way to configure Nginx in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message is right, you can't use a wildcard origin *and* credentials:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

> For requests *without credentials*, the literal value "`*`" can be specified, as a wildcard; the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials [will result in an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials).

Instead, just pass back the actual origin, the one that arrived in the Origin HTTP header, then it will always match:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
```