# CORS Error when running a pageView for ReactGA

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I am trying to add React-GA to a react web app and have followed the documentation by adding it to index.js:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('MY_ID');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

However, this results in the following error in the browser console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?......'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
> must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
> XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
>
> analytics.js:37 POST
> https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?......
> net::ERR_FAILED

Looking at the Google Analytics HTTP response in the network tab, I am definitely seeing the wildcard set for access-control-allow-headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: *
...
```

However, I am not sure how to resolve this on my end since it appears to be caused by the response from Google.

Comment: Getting the same issue in an Angular 10 app.

Comment: Try this chrome ext: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: That's weird. The header `access-control-allow-credentials` should never be combined with a wildcard value for `access-control-allow-origin`. The `access-control-allow-credentials` header unlocks credentialed requests, while a value of `access-control-allow-origin: *` is incompatible with such requests. You're also sending requests to the non-standard `j/collect` endpoint. I think you should look for a fix in your GA settings, as all React-GA does is wrap Google's `analytics.js` library, which also does not usually send credentialed requests.

Comment: This may be related: [Missing Patch method with corsheaders only on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66341353/2873538)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are **using a wildcard with a request with the credentials mode 'include'**.

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' **when the request's credentials mode is 'include**'.

**You need to specify the origin for your request to work**. here is 'http://localhost:3000'.

You can find more information on this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803394/cors-credentials-mode-is-include)

I used this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ga-example-okei4?file=/src/index.js) to test Google Analytics with 'create-react-app'.

Comment: Seems likely to be the answer. `access-control-allow-origin: *` is _never_ allowed. Wildcard is invalid for this header. Instead you need to provide a list of valid origins.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, using the ReactGa inside an userEffect, and initializing it with some userState variable example userId (optional) and marking cookieDomain as auto and enabling debug.

```
import ReactGa from 'react-ga';

useEffect(()=>{
    
    ReactGa.initialize('Tracking_Id', {
        gaOptions: {
          userId: username ? username :'Not-Logged'
        },
      'cookieDomain': 'auto',
      'debug': true
    });
    ReactGa.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
    console.log(ReactGa.ga())
       
 },[])
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use the CORS anywhere proxy, by simply just requesting to  https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?..... instead

Comment: you may not use that server