# How to set cookie on localhost from api?

Tags: reactjs, flask, cookies, localhost

I am developing a React project, when making requests from localhost to api, I receive a 'set-cookie' header in response and i need to set them, but I get an error from CORS. Using CRA, axios. *withCredentials* is added. 
On server side(Flask) added headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials.
Is it a server error or on my local dev server?

Client:

```
     axios.post('https://api.com/login', values,
       { withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      setLoading(false);
      dispatch(setUser(response.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setLoading(false);
      notification.error(error.response.data.message);
    });
```

Server:

```
 # CORS configuration
 crm_application = Flask(__name__)
 CORS(
  crm_application,
  origins=[
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://api.stemlab.by"
  ],
   supports_credentials=True
 )
 crm_application.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
```

Comment: It will be good to add the relevant pieces of code and configs here, so people can help you better.

Comment: What CORS error are you getting? What's the error message in your browser console?

Comment: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803394/cors-credentials-mode-is-include