# Solving CORS Issue using Chrome Extension

Tags: api, frontend, cors, developer-tools, requestly

[image]My app is available on app-123.company.aws.com So in order to make the development process faster, I use Requestly to redirect scripts & APIs to my local development. This works fine most of the time but some API endpoints don't have CORS enabled and hence in some workflows I get a CORS error.
I tried adding a Modify Headers Rule in Requestly like this

But I then got the following error

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

How can I solve this?

Comment: The error is somewhat self-explanatory, you need to not use `*` when responding with that header. Show how you configured CORS

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in your location directive

```
if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://app-123/.company/.aws/.com$") {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error points out, you cannot use the `*` as the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when the request's credentials mode is `include`.

When a request's credentials mode is `include`, it simply means the request is carrying either cookies or authorization headers. For security reasons, the server must return the exact origin instead of `*` as the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  [Refer to this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723981/816213)

To solve this error, you can simply configure Modify Headers rule like this

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app-123.company.aws.com
```

[image]

By looking at your setup, I assume your appId can change so Just in case, your origin can change. Requestly can automatically compute the page origin for you using a predefined function `rq_request_initiator_origin()`.  [Refer to this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/requestly/requestly/issues/622)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: rq_request_initiator_origin()
```

At the runtime, you will get a response header A`ccess-Control-Allow-Origin` based on where the request originated So if the page origin is `https://app-123.company.aws.com` it will be the value of the header.